# Pick Out Image URL From HTML

Tags: python, sed, awk, html-parsing

I'm trying to pick out the url of an image from a really long html file. The file looks something like this:

```
...Lots_of_html><a href=somelink.com>Human Readable Text</a><img src="http://image.com">....
```

I'd like to pick out the http://image.com from the above html, I've tried the following with no luck:

```
sed -n ‘s%.*src=%%;s%\".*%%p’ image_urls.txt

sed -n ‘s%.*src=%%;s%\".*%%p’ image_urls.txt


import re
rex = re.compile(r'src=.(.*?)>',re.S|re.M)
data="<long html string>"
match = rex.match(data)
```

I've not got much experience with regular expression things, so I imagine there are some basic errors being made in the above. I'd be grateful for any help but in particular I'd like to get one of the sed commands working so it's easy to integrate into a bash script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The basic error is trying to use regular expressions to parse HTML documents. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: Don't write your own code to parse HTML, and certainly don't do it with regular expressions.  Parsing HTML is a solved problem, and there are plenty of Python libraries out there that have already been written, tested and debugged so that you don't have to write, test and debug your own code to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**perl**

Since you already have two python solutions, here's one way you could do it with perl WWW::Mechanize:

```
perl -MWWW::Mechanize -e '
  $m = WWW::Mechanize->new;
  $m->get($ARGV[0]);
  $m->dump_images(undef, 1)' file://`pwd`/image_urls.txt
```

**sed**

If you can make some assumptions about the input, you may get away with a simple sed regex.

Here's how you could use sed with the test data you provided:

```
sed -n 's%.*src="\([^"]*\)".*%\1%p'
```

This captures the contents between the quotes in `\1` and removes everything else.

You could do it your way as well, being careful of what is matched. Your second substitute command removes too much. Here's one way to avoid it:

```
sed -n 's%.*src="%%; s%".*%%p'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that second command was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: That's great until you have `<img src= "foo.jpg">`, or `<img src=\n"foo.jpg">`.  You'll also be pulling out `src` attributes from tags like `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`.

Comment: @AndyLester: indeed this should only be used if assumptions about the inputs order can be made.

Comment: @AndyLester: added an html-parsing solution.

Comment: The WWW::Mechanize solution uses the `dump_images` method, but if you're going that route, you could just as well use the `images` method and manipulate them programatically rather than using the format `dump_images` uses.  `images` came first, and `dump_images` is just a convenience wrapper around it for debugging.  The `find_images` method also allows filtering of the images that it finds.  Image extraction is very common, so Mech has many conveniences to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Better use the modules `urllib2` + `lxml` using a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query. An example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# vim:ts=4:sw=4

import cookielib, urllib2
from lxml import etree

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
page = opener.open("http://stackoverflow.com/q/14129900/465183")
page.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
reddit = etree.HTML(page.read())

for img in reddit.xpath('//img/@src'):
    print img
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this as Python I would use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

> Beautiful Soup parses anything you give it, and does the tree traversal stuff for you. You can tell it "Find all the links", or "Find all the links of class externalLink", or "Find all the links whose urls match "foo.com", or "Find the table heading that's got bold text, then give me that text."

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<a href=somelink.com>Human Readable Text</a><img src="http://image.com">"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> img_tags = soup.find_all("img")
>>> for img in img_tags:
>>> ...     print img.get("src")
http://image.com
```

Or you could do it even simpler:

```
>>> soup.find_all("img", src="http://image.com")
[<img src="http://image.com"/>]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this functions.

```
#
#
# get_url_images_in_text()
#
# @param html - the html to extract urls of images from him.
# @param protocol - the protocol of the website, for append to urls that not start with protocol.
#
# @return list of images url.
#
#
def get_url_images_in_text(html, protocol):
    urls = []
    # Do regex for get all images urls, here i get only urls of png and jpg but you can add any prefix that you want.
    all_urls = re.findall(r'((http\:|https\:)?\/\/[^"\' ]*?\.(png|jpg))', html, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)
    for url in all_urls:
        if not url[0].startswith("http"):
            urls.append(protocol + url[0])
        else:
            urls.append(url[0])

    return urls

#
#
# get_images_from_url()
#
# @param url - the url for extract images url from him. 
#
# @return list of images url.
#
#
def get_images_from_url(url):
    protocol = url.split('/')[0]
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return get_url_images_in_text(resp.text, protocol)
```